# AutoSuggest with value like select list

Tags: jquery, select, autosuggest

I am, having problem in replacing traditional  list with jquery autosuggest. i have a situation where my  form  list has cities with their zip code in values i.e:

```
 <Select name="cities">
      <option value="54000">ABC</option>
      <option value="75500">XYZ</option>
      <option value="12345">JHK</option>
 </select>
```

I have the code to replace it with the autosuggest, but i dont know how to pass in value against an autosuggested option i.e. when ABC is autosuggested and form is posted 54000 should be posted.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: could you share the code ?

Comment: there isnt any code yet as i dont know exactly how to achieve this. I have made use of the jquery autosuggest plugin to simply create one autosuggest text box. thats it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mcmyLs5/) that shows me the correct value of the `select` box

I've assigned an [`ID`](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) to the `select` box and am `alert`ing the `value` assigned to it.

The `value` will be sent on `form submit` and not the `text` of the `option`

Click "show select value" to see the `value` assigned to your `select` box